# Changing #hash does not recalc/refresh page CSS in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

I am using the URL#hash to enable an HTML/CSS modal window.  When that is closed we use history.back() to revert to the previous page without creating a new history entry.

All fine in Firefox, however in IE the URL changes correctly but the actual screen is not redrawn back to the previous state.

```js
console.log("Loading page...");
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(oEvent)
 { console.log("In hashChange - location.hash = " + location.hash); } );
```

```css
div { background-color: white; }
div:target { background-color: grey; }
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="modal1">test div (modal1)</div>

 <a href="#modal1" >Open modal1</a>

 <a href="#" onclick=" history.back(); return false; ">Close modal1</a>
</body>
```

Any suggestion how to get IE to redraw the page after history.back() correctly?

Comment: Just a bit more info, I have tried replacing the history.back() with location.replaceState() but still same problem occurs.
    var newUrl = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname;
    history.replaceState({}, null, newUrl);

Comment: It's a bug in IE, no known workaround yet found.  By the way the suggestion to use location.hash=location.hash is no help as that creates a new history entry again.
Bug report: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/959007/history-replacestate-doesnt-update-scroll-position-state-to-new-hash-fragment-unlike-other-vendors